# animated .effect() jqueryui fastest click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a error when fastest click in `tabs`, see image:

[image: error ocurr in fastest click in tabs]

Here's my js:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    showcontent: function () {
        this.each(function () {
            var options = {
                direction: 'vertical'
            };
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            }, 2000)
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
                if (!$(this).is(":animated")) {
                    $(this).toggle("clip", options, 400);
                }
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
});

$("#team1").addClass('tab_over');
$("#team1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('tab_over').siblings().removeClass('tab_over');
    $('#c1').showcontent();
    return false;
});
$("#team2").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('tab_over').siblings().removeClass('tab_over');
    $('#c2').showcontent();
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="x">
    <li id="team1"><a href="#">Misión </a> 
    </li>
    <li id="team2"><a href="#">Visión</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="y">
    <li id="c1" style="">
        <div>Content 1
            <br />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="c2">
        <div>Content 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Noranterry/Cam2U/

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? What is the error you are talking about? You need to elaborate your question.

Comment: His problem lies in the fact that if you click on the navigation item too fast, the associative content will not disappear. It is because the content associated with the previous navigation item has not finished fading in yet when he tried to hide it, so the hide() function takes no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the animation that is happening on the previous one while doing fast clicks. You can use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the currently animated ones `$(':animated', '.y').stop(true, true);`: before you animate the current one. You can remove the `timeout`

```
 showcontent: function () {
        this.each(function () {

            var options = {
                direction: 'vertical'
            };
            $(':animated', '.y').stop(true, true);  // Here clear up the previous queues.
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxa8d/)

*Issue is that the previous animation is still in queue when you trigger animations for the new ones and ultimately both finishes up the animates and both of them becomes visible. Using stop with true will clear the queues which has the previous animations accumulated during the fast clicks.*

Comment: I replace :
 setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            }, 2000)
for:
$(':animated', $(this).parent()).stop(true, true);
see in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Noranterry/zYLsb/1/ 
and work thank you all

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem, you could choose to hide the Content that belongs to the respective button. This will prevent the button from sticking.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    showcontent: function () {
        this.each(function () {
            var options = {
                direction: 'vertical'
            };
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            }, 2000)
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
            } else {
                $(this).siblings('li').hide();
                if (!$(this).is(":animated")) {
                    $(this).toggle("clip", options, 400);
                }
            }
        });
        return this;
    }
});

$("#team1").addClass('tab_over');
$("#team1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('tab_over').siblings().removeClass('tab_over');
    $('#c1').showcontent();
    $('#c2').hide(0);
    return false;
});
$("#team2").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('tab_over').siblings().removeClass('tab_over');
    $('#c2').showcontent();
    $('#c1').hide(0);
    return false;
});
```